# How do I tell the GitHub CLI to use a specific SSH key?

Tags: ssh, github-cli

I have various GitHub accounts and for each account I have SSH set up. So under `~/.ssh` I have a public and private key for each account.

I want to use the GitHub CLI, but I am not sure how I can tell the CLI to use a particular SSH key.

In case it is relevant, this is what I get when I run `ssh-add -l`:

[image]

**Example Scenario**

I want to run `gh repo create` on GitHub account `B`, but for some reason, the repo got created on GitHub account `A`. Is there a way I can tell `gh` what account to use?

Comment: Does Github CLI (`gh`) uses ssh protocol at all? Do you mean `git` command line? Git is not Github CLI but can be used with Github.

Comment: Yeah, you can make it use ssh via `git config set`. Yep I'm talking about `gh` (the CLI, I know Git and the GitHub CLI are two different things).

Comment: If you mean `gh config set git_protocol ssh` — that's not about  Github CLI, it's the protocol to use for **git clone and push** operations. See https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_config. So the question remains: are you talking about using `gh` with SSH or `git`?

Comment: Good catch! I'm still talking about `gh` though.

Comment: I don't think `gh repo create` runs over SSH. It's a [Github API](https://docs.github.com/ru/rest) call so it runs over HTTPS. You need [`gh auth logout`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_logout) and [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have different *GitHub* users the gh-cli won't be very effective. as @phd commands like `gh repo create` require logging in via an auth token. https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login

Switching contexts between accounts (i.e. github.com/user1 and github.com/user2) def doesn't seem supported so you'd have to hack around loging in and out each time every time you switched.

But configuring which ssh key `git` should use can be configured easily enough in some combo of `~/.ssh/config` `.gitconfig` and/or setting the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` env var before running git commands.

Comment: Thanks, so it isn't currently supported.