# How to run "gh repo create" with a specific user/SSH key?

Tags: github, github-cli

I'm struggling with git/SSH multiple identities (one personal/work and one dedicated to yet another company)

I've managed to somehow create a virtual local "routing" thanks to https://simonbasle.github.io/2017/10/git-identities-and-ssh/, which selects the right SSH key depending on where the local repo is located on the disk. That's a first good step.

But I'm struggling to adapt my "gh" commands:

```
gh repo create REPO_NAME \
--template USER_NAME/TEMPLATE_NAME \
--private \
--clone
```

Doing this somehow successfully creates the REPO_NAME repository in the USER_NAME account, but then it fails at the "clone" step, with `ERROR: Repository not found.`.

I believe that's because `gh` doesn't use the right SSH key, but I don't understand how to specify which one to choose from.

Comment: I'm no expert on `gh` but my understanding is that when it creates a repository, it uses the GitHub v3 API via https (only), even if it later uses ssh to clone the created repository. You might be best off using `gh` to create it, and then `git clone` with the adjusted URL as in the article you referenced. That is, your `gh repo create` *is not* using ssh. By doing `git clone` yourself, rather than with `gh`, you can control the URL you supply.

Comment: Still, there may be a way to get the `--clone` option to work. I adjusted your tags to reach `gh` experts.

Comment: I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74644191/how-do-i-tell-the-github-cli-to-use-a-specific-ssh-key which seems to say "this isn't yet supported".

Answer (score 0):

This gist helped me solved this problem(before that, talked to AI for a while, chaos info provided, wasting time), hope it can help you as well(which should):

https://gist.github.com/yermulnik/017837c01879ed3c7489cc7cf749ae47

Let me summarize what I did:

Get tokens for two(or more) github accounts, visit:
https://github.com/settings/tokens

Choose Personal access tokens (classic), select repo, read org, delete repo, no expiration.

cd gh config folder and open with vs code:

```
cd ~/.config/gh
```

modify config.yml, set git_protocol: ssh(if you use ssh keys), and add alias:

```
personal: "!cp ~/.config/gh/hosts.yml.personal ~/.config/gh/hosts.yml && gh auth status"
work: "!cp ~/.config/gh/hosts.yml.work ~/.config/gh/hosts.yml && gh auth status"
```

create two files:

```
hosts.yml.personal
```

content:

```
github.com:
oauth_token: ghp_xxx
git_protocol: ssh
user: user1
```

2nd file:

```
hosts.yml.work
```

content:

```
github.com:
oauth_token: ghp_xxx
git_protocol: ssh
user: user2
```

Now you can switch by:

```
gh personal
```

and

```
gh work
```

Try this:

```
gh repo list
```

Hope it helps!